# How to get vertical spacing using a bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a tough time wrapping my mind around how to achieve vertical spacing with the [bootstrap grid system](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp).  I want one box to be 1/3 from the top and left and another to take up 1/3 from the bottom, but be full-width.  I have three rows right now spanning 12, 6, and 12 columns respectively:

An example layout using [draw.io](http://www.draw.io):

[image]

Within the `body` tag of `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
          <h1><strong>I am strong<strong><span class="lead">i am less strong</span></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/third-party/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/third-party/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Right now this is a request for a theme, not a question. Can you include what you've tried that isn't working and explain what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Rows and columns don't work the way you're trying to use them. Your explanation of `1/3` is a bit confusing. The info in your question conflicts with your code. I don't see three rows spanning 12, 6 and 12 columns.

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to force the height of your container to fill the whole page with a line of jQuery. You don't need jQuery for this, but I noticed that you already include it on your page.

The markup:

```
<div class="container full-page-height">
  <div class="row offset-top-third">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 white">
      <h1>Hey you!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row offset-bottom-third">
    <div class="bgimg">Background image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.bgimg {
    background: #333;
    color: #eee;
}

.white {
    background: #fff;
}

.offset-top-third {
    position:relative;
    top: 33.333%;
    height: 33.333%;
    background: #888;
}

.offset-bottom-third {
    position:relative;
    top: 66.667%;
    height: 33.333%;
    background: #888;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  $(".full-page-height").css({height: h});
});
```

The [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GHczrBgkgR).

Answer (score 0):

If your vertical columns are div's, then give each one a `margin` value in pixels to space them away from each other. Then set the `width` of each column to a percent value so they fit the whole window.

Comment: To translate into bootstrap terms, 'vertical columns are div's' = `.row`.....'set the width' = use `.col....` classes